# Multiple connection errors with Sublime Text and SFTP

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp

Since a while I get the following problems with SFTP:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftp_transport.py", line 189, in handle_ftp_error
>   File "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftp_transport.py", line 105, in do_connect File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftplib2.py", line 471, in login File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftplib2.py", line 307, in sendcmd File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftplib2.py", line 276, in getresp
>   SFTP.sftp.ftplib2.error_perm: 530 Sorry, the maximum number of clients
>   (10) for this user are already connected.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/threads.py", line 15, in run_with_except_hook
>   File "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/file_transfer.py", line 55, in run File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/file_transfer.py", line 182, in clone File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftp_transport.py", line 157, in connect File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftp_transport.py", line 145, in connect File
>   "/Users/wbond/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/SFTP/sftp/ftp_transport.py", line 295, in handle_ftp_error
>   SFTP.sftp.errors.AuthenticationError: Invalid login/password specified

In console I just have this concerning the SFTP Plugin:

> warning: mnemonic b not found in menu caption SFTP/FTP warning:
>   mnemonic b not found in menu caption SFTP/FTP

I can not found anything helpful in www.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? What are you doing to generate it? Have you read any of the official [support docs](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/support) for SFTP? Did you generate a debug log and send it to the support address? This is a commercial product, so any issues with it should first be addressed with its author, assuming of course that you've purchased a license.

Comment: I also receive these errors along with another one where it tries to upload a file/folder not on the project whenever I save. I emailed support 6 months ago and again 3 months ago - I have yet to receive a reply from the author.. @MattDMo: this error is generated in the console on startup or a reload.